# How to call a function in TabActivity from a child activity?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I want to update the title of the tab according to the content of my child activity.

However, when I call:

```
TabActivity parent = (TabActivity) getParent();
TabHost parentHost = (TabHost) parent.getTabHost().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

in the child, the program crashes. **(Thanks StinePike) Now I know I cannot get the instance of TabHost, but still, I can't call the methods defined in my own TabActivity. **

Anyone can help me discover the problem and solve it?

My TabActivity setup:

```
public class Tab extends TabActivity {  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        View newTab = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabmini, null);
        TextView text0 = (TextView) newTab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
        text0.setText("new tab");

        tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(newTab).setContent(new Intent(this, BrowserActivity.class)));

    }

    public void addTab(String startPage){
        //...Add a new Tab  
    }   
    public void setTabTitle(String title){
        //...Set new title  
    }   

}
```

Comment: Can you please paste your LogCat output ?

Comment: seems that error is caused by null pointer exception...Can't the program find my own methods in my TabActivity?

Comment: @user1731839 how did you resolved `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 3):

from child call

```
RootActivity parentActivity;
parentActivity = (YourRootActivity) this.getParent();
parentActivity.setTitle(title);
```

In parent define `setTitle(String s)` method

```
public void setTitle(String s){
 // set title here
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I can get the instance of parentActivity, but when I try to call the method in my own tabActivity, a null pointer exception appears.

Answer (score 0):

TabActivity is deprecated (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).  Please consider using something else:

- Regular activity with a tabhost + viewpager (http://dewful.com/?p=15)
- Actionbar tabs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

Comment: The problem is still the same when I use regular activity.